# Top tabview with scrollable header using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mobile, cross-platform

i would like to achieve something like this

[image]

1. The YELLOW part should be scrollable up/down and should drag the rest of the page with it. meaning i can hide it if i scroll up and leave the rest of the page displayed
2. BLUE part should be selectable, and contents of it should be displayed on the RED part (side scrolling)

-Ive looked on the net on the net and considered tabbed pages, but tabbed pages cant have headers
-Im considering carousel view inside a stack layout but im still constructing a POC for it.

maybe somebody here has done it using xamarin.forms.
Can somebody point me out to what controls can i use to achieve this in xamarin.forms? thank you!

Comment: at least explain the downvote for the question

Answer (score 3):

I would achieve that with Sharpnado tabs https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs (for tabs only) or https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms (for all Sharpnado goodness).

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: thank you, i have already seen this beforehand and must say it is a choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some third-party Nuget, you can look at [TabView](https://github.com/chaosifier/TabView).

Install **Xam.Plugin.TabView** nuget.

Initialize the CarouselView plugin first before using TabView in your iOS and Android projects.

For example in Android(ios is similar to this):

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
   
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
    }
}
```

use in your page.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:tabview="clr-namespace:Xam.Plugin.TabView;assembly=Xam.Plugin.TabView"
         x:Class="xxxx">
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200">
            <Image Source="bd_logo1.png"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <tabview:TabViewControl
            HeaderBackgroundColor="White"
            HeaderSelectionUnderlineColor="Transparent"
            HeaderTabTextColor="Black"
            HeaderTabTextFontAttributes="Bold"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            TabHeaderSpacing="100"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <tabview:TabViewControl.ItemSource>
                <tabview:TabItem HeaderText="About">
                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Source="pic.png"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </tabview:TabItem>
                <tabview:TabItem HeaderText="Photos">
                    <Label
                        FontSize="Large"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="Hello There!"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </tabview:TabItem>
                <tabview:TabItem  HeaderText="Albums">
                    <ListView>
                        <ListView.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                                <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                                <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                                <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                                <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                                <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                                <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                                <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                            </x:Array>
                        </ListView.ItemsSource>
                    </ListView>
                </tabview:TabItem>
            </tabview:TabViewControl.ItemSource>
        </tabview:TabViewControl>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

If you don't want to use the third-party nuget,you could use a StackLayout with three Label and a [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/introduction) to achieve it,

Something like:

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image ...></Image>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="About"></Label>
            <Label Text="Photos"></Label>
            <Label Text="Albums"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <CarouselView x:Name ="carouseview">
            ...
        </CarouselView>
     </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

then add the click event to the Labels,and call `carouseview.ScrollTo(position)` to navigate to the relative page.

**Note**:it's just an idea, and you have to do it yourself.You also could use colletionview instead of the StackLayout above as a tab,then handle its `SelectionChanged` event and let carouseview scroll to the relative page.

Comment: revisiting old questions, and yes i have used Carouselview for this one.